# Using ngClass properly in Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, ngfor, ng-class

For the following snippet,

```
<tr *ngFor= "let rec of csvHead; let first=first"
[ngClass] = "{'title':first}">
</tr>
```

the class "title" is successfully added to the <tr>. But I can't find the reason. I guess the value should be either :true or :false instead of :first in

```
"{'title':first}"
```

Comment: The reason it is added to the `tr` is because it is the first `tr` that is created, you'll find that every other `tr` that is created won't have the class `title`

Comment: What is your condition for enabling/disabling the class?

Answer (score 0):

`ngClass` directive supports these forms:

```
 *     <some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>
 *     <some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>
 *     <some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>
 *     <some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">...</some-element>
 *     <some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

and you use the third form that keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression given in the value evaluates to a **TRUTHY** value (*not true or false value*), otherwise they are removed,

---

NOTE: the `first` is an expression that for first row evaluates to true